# Tap/Mobile solution for buttons which reveal link with "hover"

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, css-transitions

I have a set of buttons which flip over onhover to reveal the link. I thought I could modify them to work on touch devices too, but I'm striggling. Ideally, I would like the mobile/touch user to be able to tap the button and reveal the link (the first tap emulating the "hover" function) - i've tried for a few hours and I don't seem to be getting anywhere - is there an easier way to do this and get the behavior i'm after?

My current code is below:

https://codepen.io/UnluckyForSome/pen/bGmLGWg

HTML:

```
            <article class="panel" id="findme">
              <header>
                <h2>Find Me!</h2>
              </header>
              <p>Find me anywhere!</p>
              <div class="cube flip-to-top">
                <div class="default-state github">
                  <i class="icon brands fa-github"></i> GitHub
                </div>
                <div class="active-state">
                  <a href="https://example.com/unluckyforsome">@Example</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="cube flip-to-top">
                <div class="default-state linkedin"">
                  <i class=" icon brands fa-linkedin"></i> LinkedIn </div>
                <div class="active-state">
                  <a href="https://example.com/unluckyforsome">@Example</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="cube flip-to-top">
                <div class="default-state twitter">
                  <i class="icon brands fa-twitter"></i> Twitter
                </div>
                <div class="active-state">
                  <a href="https://example.com/unluckyforsome">@Example</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="cube flip-to-top">
                <div class="default-state instagram">
                  <i class="icon brands fa-instagram"></i> Instagram
                </div>
                <div class="active-state">
                  <a href="https://example.com/unluckyforsome">@Example</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="cube flip-to-top">
                <div class="default-state facebook">
                  <i class="icon brands fa-facebook"></i> Facebook
                </div>
                <div class="active-state">
                  <a href="https://example.com/unluckyforsome">@Example</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </article>
```

CSS:

```
  .cube {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 250ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 250ms ease;
    transition: all 250ms ease;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  
  .default-state,.active-state {
    height: 50px;
  }
  .cube +.cube:not(:last-child){
  margin:10px 0px;
  }

  .default-state {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(25px);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(25px);
    -o-transform: translateZ(25px);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(25px);
    transform: translateZ(25px);
  }
  .flip-to-top .active-state {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(75px);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(75px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(75px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(75px);
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(75px);
  }
  .flip-to-bottom .active-state {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-50px);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-50px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-50px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-50px);
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-50px);
  }
  .cube.flip-to-top:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-89deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-89deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-89deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-89deg);
    transform: rotateX(-89deg);
  }
  .cube.flip-to-bottom:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(89deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(89deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(89deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(89deg);
    transform: rotateX(89deg);
  }
  .cube {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .default-state {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: background 250ms ease;
    -moz-transition: background 250ms ease;
    -o-transition: background 250ms ease;
    transition: background 250ms ease;
    background-color: #222222;
    transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

.active-state {
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #333333;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.active-state a {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: deepskyblue;
}



  .linkedin {
    background: #0077b5;
  }
  .github {
    background: #171515;
  }
  .facebook {
    background: #3B5998;
  }
  .twitter {
    background: #1DA1F2;
  }
  .instagram {
    background: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 35% 90%, #fec564, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 0 140%, #fec564, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 0 -25%, #5258cf, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 20% -50%, #5258cf, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 100% 0, #893dc2, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 60% -20%, #893dc2, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 100% 100%, #d9317a, transparent), linear-gradient(#6559ca, #bc318f 30%, #e33f5f 50%, #f77638 70%, #fec66d 100%);
  }

  .default-state i {
    margin-right: 10px
  }
```

Many thanks in advance! :D

I've tried some javascript solutions but I can't get them to behave correctly. One solution I was able to get the first tap to display the link, but this broke the normal browser hover functionality.

Comment: I test your pen on my android using chrome and it works as expected. first click - reveal, second - follow link. What do you mean `I would like the mobile/touch user to be able to tap the button and reveal the link`